# Sql Query to update a column that contains other column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update

I am new to sql queries. I am trying to do the below operation and could not achieve the functionality successfully. Any point would help.
[image: Table with name and alias]

1. I have a table with name column and alias column.
2. There are few names with alias included in them
3. I am trying to filer names which have alias included in that column. These alias should be match the alias column in the same row.
4. Get all names which have alias in them and remove alias from the name.

I am trying to remove alias from the names in sql table with a update query.

```
select * from tbltest 
    where studentName like CONCAT('%', alias, '%')

    UPDATE tbltest SET studentName = REPLACE(studentName, CONCAT('%', alias, '%'));
```

Comment: Are all aliases in brackets as shown?

Comment: yes they are same as the alias column. Name column has data with some records concatenated with alias. I am trying to remove those alias from name column data. This is test data. Original record count is more than the test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all aliases are embedded in the format shown then to get rid of them and the surrounding brackets you can use.

```
UPDATE tbltest 
SET studentName = REPLACE(studentName, CONCAT('(', alias, ')'), '')
WHERE studentName LIKE CONCAT('%(', alias, ')%')
```

Adding case where concat doesnt work

```
UPDATE tbltest 
SET studentName = REPLACE(studentName, '('+ alias+ ')', '')
WHERE studentName LIKE ('%('+ alias+ ')%')
```

Comment: I tried to test the update statement but it shows 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.I am using sql 2012. any suggestions

Comment: @Chandana either the server isnt using 2012 or the compatibility level must be lower. Just use `+’ instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the pointer. I updated answer with + case.

Comment: Thanks I was too lazy to do it on IPad!